# Feeding my baby milk that I stored from when he was 3 days old and on

Tags: breastfeeding

I am strictly breastfeeding and have been pumping and storing milk since my baby was 3 days old. When he turns a month old, I want to introduce bottles with breastmilk so anyone else can feed him if I am not home. Is it okay to give him the milk from those first days of pumping? I understand those first couple of bags are mainly the colostrum. Does this matter once he's a month old, or is milk milk?

Comment: How have you been storing the milk?

Answer (score 8):

To *some* extent milk is milk, but the nutritional content shifts gradually over time to meet the growth patterns of a baby (and also again around weaning).

At about a month, your milk generally has more fat and less protein than breastmilk from Day 3.

Feeding him that milk isn't unsafe* or unhealthy, but perhaps consider mixing half Day 3 milk and half "now" milk. Not only will the nutrients be more balanced, but also the flavors -- if your baby gets a different *taste* in addition to the different nipple from a bottle, I think it will be harder to get him to accept it. (Two of my breastfed/bottle-fed babies had no issues with accepting bottle feeding, one fought it like crazy -- simplifying the transition can only help!)

*** NOTE: This assumes the milk has been frozen properly.** La Leche League has a [useful table of acceptable storage times](http://www.llli.org/faq/milkstorage.html) depending on storage method (countertop, fridge, freezer, deep freeze).

---

In case you really want to look at the nutritional components of breastmilk in great detail to help you make your decision, the science-heavy quotes below are pulled from an article by Ann Prentice, published by the United Nations University Press, *[Constituents of human milk](http://archive.unu.edu/unupress/food/8F174e/8F174E04.htm).*

> The composition of breastmilk is not uniform, and the concentrations of many of its constituents change during the lactation period and differ between individual mothers.
>
> Human lactation can be divided into four phases that differ in the
>   composition and volume of milk produced: colostral, transitional,
>   mature, and involutional. Colostrum is secreted for the first three to
>   five days after delivery, transitional milk until the end of the
>   second week, mature milk during full lactation, and involutional milk
>   at the end of lactation. These definitions are arbitrary; the timing
>   varies from one mother to another, and composition does not change
>   abruptly. Typical concentrations of selected milk constituents are
>   shown in table 3. Notably, colostrum is rich in secretory
>   IgA, lactoferrin, vitamin A, and sodium compared with mature milk but
>   has relatively low concentrations of fat, lactose, and vitamin B1.... Because milk
>   volume is low during the colostral phase, rising slowly during the
>   first week to the higher levels of established lactation, the
>   daily intake of most milk components by breastfed babies increases
>   after birth, reaching a peak after several weeks (table 4). The
>   exception is ... total protein intake, which is
>   maximal in the first week (table 4).
>
> Mature breastmilk composition also changes during the course of
>   lactation, although not as markedly as in the early weeks....

Comment: Excellent answer. I got lost when searching for references myself...